# Running 10.13.4 Beta (17E182a), what is "Messages in iCloud currently disabled" message I am getting?

Tags: icloud, messages, data-synchronization, beta-seed-program

See picture below.
I am seeing "Messages in iCloud is currently disabled. Repair Account."
The "repair account" is not clickable. I have enabled Messages in iCloud and I have tried to sync several times but nothing happens. I am not sure what other steps to take. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What happens after a restart? Is the internet connection (wired or wifi) working? Can you login to other iCloud services? Have you tried logging out of iCloud in System Preferences > iCloud? Maybe there's just an authentication problem and iCloud needs to reconnected.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: I uploaded the newest beta a day or two ago, so 10.13.4 Beta (17E182a).

Comment: I am on wifi. Every other service and function is running fine. I have logged out of iCloud and logged back in and the issue still persists. I realize it may be an error due to running the beta, but I haven't seen any other mentions of this issue.

Comment: If you're running a beta version, please [edit] your question to include that info.  Also, see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.

Comment: After some playing around, I think this may be related to file transfers. If you open your file transfers window (⌘⌥L), do you see lots of pending downloads?

Comment: @BallpointBen There are no pending downloads

Answer (score -1):

Go to your settings and confirm your iCloud password, this worked for me, I had the same problem.Hope this works if you haven’t already figured it out!

Answer (score -1):

It’s a bug with the 11.3 iOS update. Pretty good screw up by Apple. Doesn’t appear to effect functionality

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Do you have a reference for this bug? Also, can you expand your answer to explain how this relates to the question (which itself is about macOS and not iOS)?